# How to append four column values into two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to append Four column values to Two column values. Please help on this request. I tried with below query but couldn't make it possible.

```
select * from 
 (SELECT DISTINCT id,'A' as Name FROM emp1) tbl1 
FUll OUTER JOIN 
 (SELECT DISTINCT id,'B' as Name FROM emp2 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT DISTINCT id,'B' as Name FROM emp3) tbl2
on tbl1.id = tbl2.id where tbl1.id IS NULL or tbl2.id IS NULL;
```

Query Output:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: You have two examples of expected output and they are not the same.  That is rather confusing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Update my question

Answer (score 1):

Seems like unpivoting the data, with a `VALUES` table construct, would work here:

```sql
SELECT V.ID,
       V.Name
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(YT.ID1, YT.Name1), --Your table had 2 ID & Name columns, which isn't allowed.
                        (YT.ID2, YT.Name2))V(ID,Name) --I therefore assumed they were suffixed with 1 and 2.
WHERE V.ID != 'None';
```

Though base on your attempt, not the example data, are you not just after a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` query?

```sql
SELECT id, 'A'
FROM emp1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'B'
FROM emp2
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'C'
FROM emp3;
```

Of course, if you have 3 emp tables like that, you do also have a design flaw.